# CentOS 7 - Won't accept any SSL certificates

Tags: centos, ssl

I have a problem on my CentOS 7 box doing anything that requires SSL, including curl, wget or updating via YUM.

The output is always the same:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl -I -v https://google.com
* About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.138.100...
* Connected to google.com (74.125.138.100) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Jun 16 08:37:32 2016 GMT
*       expire date: Sep 08 08:29:00 2016 GMT
*       common name: *.google.com
*       issuer: CN=192.168.2.44,C=US
* NSS error -8172 (SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER)
* Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

All certificates appear to be "marked as not trusted" (I've tried this with a dozen different URLs). I tried reintalling CA certificates doing this:

`yum --disablerepo="epel" reinstall ca-certificates`

but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, I'll still upvote any answers with helpful information, but I was only able to resolve this by reinstalling CentOS, so I won't be able to test any solutions as this point.

Answer (score 3):

I would check out your nss installation. It's possible that is out of date / corrupted in some way.

Check the version you are running; latest on centos 7 should be:

```
nss-config version
3.21.0
```

Then check if any nss packages have been modified / corrupted:

```
rpm -Vv nss-*
```

Depending on your results, an nss update or reinstall may be required.

You can semi-definitively see if it is an issue with nss by temporarily changing the permissions on that directory (as root):

```
chmod 400 /etc/pki/nssdb/*
```

Then issue the curl command as a regular user - if it works, it will output something like this:

```
* Connected to google.com (172.217.4.206) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unable to initialize NSS database
* Initializing NSS with certpath: none
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
<clipped>
```

Which indicates that it just used the CA certs and not the nssdb based authentication.

If this isn't a nss related problem, here is a [RHEL guide](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003) that applies to CentOS as well that walks through ensuring you have a clean CA cert configuration. I don't believe that link is behind their paywall; let me know if you need it and can't access it.

Comment: When I run `nss-config version` I get command not found for `nss-config`. Is that the right command? I'm not familiar with NSS

Comment: That's part of nss-utils I believe. What does rpm -qa | grep nss-  return?

Comment: Unfortunately I ran out of time and had to reinstall CentOS on the box. I upvoted since your answer was likely applicable, but I can't test any further. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

**What environment are you running CentOS7 under?**

There is an nasty bug related to **Centos 6.8** update  / NSS 3.21.0-8.el6 on systems under (Zen) virtualization and/or CPU AES support. 
I've experienced the issue after CentOS 6.8 & NSS update on both Rackspace & AWS t1.micro instances.

I believe you are having a related issue with an Centos7 NSS update.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58002

https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10930#c26705

How to check that AES-NI is supported by my CPU?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14077/how-to-check-that-aes-ni-is-supported-by-my-cpu

**On 6.8**, Some people have succeeded in **downgrading NSS by setting the environment variable: "NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1"**

```
# NSS_DISABLE_HW_AES=1
# yum downgrade nss nss-util nss-tools nss-sysinit
# yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
# yum versionlock add! nss-3.21.0-0.3.el6_7.x86_64 nss-sysinit-3.21.0-0.3.el6_7.x86_64 nss-tools-3.21.0-0.3.el6_7.x86_64 nss-util-3.21.0-0.3.el6_7.x86_64
```

**Again the above code is for 6.8 NOT CentOS 7**

I found nss-3.21.0-0.3.**el6_7**.x86_64 depreciated and unavailable.  I've reloaded the entire server from a image backup prior to the 6.8 update and YUM version locked nss nss-sysinit nss-tools nss-util before updating again.

NOTE: I would add the above info as a 'comment' NOT an 'answer' but my low rep score prevents me from commenting, I can only 'answer'.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but still no dice, same error. I ended up reinstalling to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Granted it is most likely my own gaffau.

It was necessary to install `*nss-*`

```
[not showing this]# nss-config version

bash: nss-config: command not found

yum install -y nss-*

Installed:
  nss-devel.x86_64 0:3.36.0-7.el7_5
  nss-pam-ldapd.x86_64 0:0.8.13-16.el7
  nss-pkcs11-devel.x86_64 0:3.36.0-7.el7_5
  nss-softokn-devel.x86_64 0:3.36.0-5.el7_5
  nss-softokn-freebl-devel.x86_64 0:3.36.0-5.el7_5
  nss-util-devel.x86_64 0:3.36.0-1.el7_5

Dependency Installed:
  nscd.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7            nspr-devel.x86_64 0:4.19.0-1.el7_5

nss-config version

Usage: nss-config [OPTIONS] [LIBRARIES]

Options:
        [--prefix[=DIR]]
        [--exec-prefix[=DIR]]
        [--includedir[=DIR]]
        [--libdir[=DIR]]
        [--version]
        [--libs]
        [--cflags]

Dynamic Libraries:
        nss
        nssutil
        ssl
        smime

[not showing this still]# nss-config --version
3.36.0
```